# Azure Functions in Visual Studio - PATH to log files?

Tags: azure-functions, visual-studio-2019

Using Visual Studio 2019 Community (on Windows 10) to create an Azure HTTP Timer trigger using C# -- code is IDENTICAL to that shown at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#example

I am able to run the project (locally) without issue.

**Question:**

I cannot find any documentation as to the actual PATH the "logger" is using when writing to the log while running locally in Visual Studio.  For example is a log file or (database) located somewhere in the project directory or on C:\somewhere?   Does anyone know where to find the log file / database?   There seems to be no method or property in the logger interface that exposes this information.

Also - perhaps there is some sort of "path" setting that needs to be configured in the "local.settings.json" file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What language are you using? Did you search for `"*.log"` in your project folder? IIRC for Java Function, when I run using `gradle azureFunctionRun` on my Ubuntu box, it creates a `build/<app>/<function>` folder and there was a log file in there. But it would also depend on what appenders you have configured in your `log4j.xml`

Comment: Same language as show in the example link: C#

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set `"fileLoggingMode": "always"` in `host.json`:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "always",
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
}
```

Then go to `C:\Users\yourusernameonlocal\AppData\Local\Temp\LogFiles\Application\Functions\Function\yourfunctionname`